# Verifying response call with JAX WS in Java

Tags: java, web-services, soap, jax-ws, webservice-client

I have a question about `jax ws` with **Java**.
In fact i have a client that call a `web service` method :

**Client Implementation** :

```
      URL url = new URL("file:/D:/Projects/Mywsdl.wsdl");
      QName qname = new QName("http://adresse/", "ImpWSService");
      Service service = Service.create(url, qname);
          //web service Interface
      DomaineIntWS domaineIntWS = service.getPort(DomaineIntWS.class);
          //web service methode call   
      String echo = scciProxyIntWS.echocall("xxx");
```

**WS Interface** :

```
         import javax.jws.WebParam;
         import javax.jws.WebService;

         @WebService
         public abstract interface DomaineIntWS
         {
         public abstract String echocall(@WebParam(name="testEcho") String paramString);
         }
```

My question is how can I add in my client implementation a way that can test the call of ws result for example testing if code response equal 200 OK ?

How can I do that with jax ws?

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to cast your Port to a BindingProvider, like this:

```
    URL url = new URL("file:/D:/Projects/Mywsdl.wsdl");
    QName qname = new QName("http://adresse/", "ImpWSService");
    Service service = Service.create(url, qname);
    //web service Interface
    DomaineIntWS domaineIntWS = service.getPort(DomaineIntWS.class);
    try {
    String echo = domaineIntWS.echocall("xxx");
    } catch (Exception e) {
      //do something with a possible exception
    } finally {

    BindingProvider bpDomaineIntWS = (BindingProvider) domaineIntWS;
    int httpResponseCode =(Integer) bpDomaineIntWS.getResponseContext().get(MessageContext.HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE);

}
```

Side note:
Have into account that even if you get the value of the response code, the JAX-WS implementation will handle the response.

In most cases, you shouldn't worry about handling yourself the codes and stuff. That is the whole purpose of JAX-WS. Otherwise you would be using a raw HttpClient library.